# cron job in Cakephp 3.4

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron, command

Environment:

Server: Xampp apache

PHP: 7.1.33

I am going to call a function by schedule, I was tried to do this with cron job.

But I am new to cron and cakephp.

What I want to know is how can I run a controller function weekly (the run time will be setted by admin, especially date:one from sunday to saturday, and time: xx:xx) in cakephp.

So I want to if admin set date and time then let the server automatically run a function on that date and time recursively.

Comment: I just want to run it in controller when admin saves the setting.

Comment: Sorry, you want it to run automatically as a cron job, or you want it to run in a controller when an admin does something? Those are entirely different scenarios.

Comment: @SeniorWebdeveloper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991651/cake-3-x-how-to-setup-a-queue-technology-for-jobs-and-news-feeds

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Comment: Hi @GregSchmidt, I want to run a cron job in controller when admin saves settings :)

Comment: Then use a queue ( https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue ). That is not a cronjob but async script (queue task)

Comment: Hi @mark, can I run a controller/plugin function every week using the queue plugin?

Comment: No, my answer was to " I want to run a cron job in controller when admin saves settings". Don't change your question completely 100 degrees all the time. It makes it impossible to understand what the problem is.